# Angular - change detection in dynamically loaded module/component without using `ChangeDetectorRef`

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-dynamic-components, change-detector-ref

I compile an Angular module (to load the module dynamically) with compiler's `compileModuleAsync` and want to insert a component of the module into view.

I tried to insert the component into `ViewContainer` but the component doesn't detect changes automatically. I should call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges` each time when I update a component's property.

Is there any way to achieve this without using the `changeDetectorRef`?

Angular version is `10.0.4`.

Example code that I load the component:

---

The Component where I load another component:

```html
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

```js
@ViewChild('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef })
dynamic: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private injector: Injector
) {}

async ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Load a module dynamically
    const exampleModule = await import('../example/example.module').then(m => m.ExampleModule);
    const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(exampleModule);
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.resolveComponent();
    const ref = container.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);
}
```

---

ExampleModule:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ExampleComponent
    ],
    imports: [...]
})
export class ExampleModule {
    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

    public resolveComponent(): ComponentFactory<ExampleComponent> {
        return this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ExampleComponent);
    }
}
```

An example case of calling `detectChanges`:

**ExampleComponent**

```html
<button (click)="toggle()">Show/Hide</button>
<span *ngIf="show">Show</span>
```

```js
public toggle() {
  this.show = !this.show;
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <- I want to not use this.
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the input to your component? Where do you call changeDetectorRef?

Comment: hi @David, passing inputs is fine, i updated the question. Just want to make it detectchanges automatically.

Comment: This seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4bcode?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts

Comment: oh i can see it works. but it doesnt work from my side

Comment: Can you try on stackblitz with your real code maybe?

Comment: It' same as you did. I'm not sure what makes the difference.

Comment: Maybe create a github repo showing your issue?

Comment: hmm i am not able to do that since it's a private repo

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-and-service I created stackblitz very similar to my app, but it seems to be working on it... not sure what's going on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this service to create component an set inputs:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formField]'
})
export class FormFieldDirective implements Field, OnChanges, OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() config: FieldConfig;
  @Input() lang: string;
  @Input() group: FormGroup;

  @Input('class') classList: string = 'col-12';

  component: ComponentRef<Field>;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private container: ViewContainerRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.component) {
      this.component.instance.config = this.config;
      this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!components[this.config.type]) {
      const supportedTypes = Object.keys(components).join(', ');
      throw new Error(
        `Trying to use an unsupported type (${this.config.type}).
        Supported types: ${supportedTypes}`
      );
    }
    const component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<Field>(components[this.config.type]);
    this.component = this.container.createComponent(component);
    this.renderer.addClass(this.component.location.nativeElement, this.config.widthClass ? this.config.widthClass : 'col-12');
    this.component.instance.config = this.config;
    this.component.instance.group = this.group;
    this.component.instance.lang = this.lang;
    if (this.config.type === ModelType.group) {
      this.component.instance.innerForm = this.group.get(this.config.name) as FormGroup;
    }

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.config.label += 'cica';
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div [ngClass]="formClass" [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of config;" formField [config]="field" [lang]="lang" [group]="form"> </ng-container>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your dynamic component detect changes automatically?

Comment: I haven't tried because I use store and forn-control to pass data, so my inputs cannot be changed. But if the input of the wrappercomponent changed, it should reflect to it if you pass it to the instance or should be rerendered if there's no other option. I'll give it a try.

Comment: yes it will work on init. but inside the component, i do some operations and the values will be updated. In that case, the component view is not updated since it doesnt listen to the changes. I had to call changeDetectorRef manually each time.

Comment: I've changed my example. If I change the input its value reflected to the dynamic component(ngAfterViewInit)

Comment: @yash, couldn't you run these operations in OnChange hook?

Comment: @alou, my purpose it to trigger the OnChange hook up on my operations..